# Use Swift Array of Strings in Switch/Case

Tags: arrays, swift

I want to be able to use any of the strings in an array `[String]` as a particular `case` statement in a Swift `switch` like this:

```
var yummy = ["apple", "banana", "orange"]

switch fruit{
  case "pineapple":
    //...
  case "mango":
    //...
  case yummy: //<-- apple, banana, or orange would satisfy this case
   //...
  default:break
}
```

How can I convert `yummy` to have each of its items checked for a match in that `case` statement?

Comment: mmh, I don't think you can do have 'pineapple'/'mango' as case statements unless you add those an enumeration. i.e. enum Yummy { case pineapple, case mango, etc }

Comment: using a for loop to iterate over the strings in yummy doesn't work for you?